# Loading unstructered data with different delimiters in Pig using PigLatin only

Tags: apache-pig

Hi I am trying to load the following data (inculdes different delimiters and is unstructered) into Pig using PigLatin only, without preparing the data with i.e. Java.

**Input:**

```
1234 #one,#two,#three
5679 #one,#two
1234 #one
```

**Output what I am looking for:**

```
1234 #one
1234 #two
1234 #three
5678 #one
5678 #two
1234 #one
```

Any ideas? Is this even possible in Pig? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: We can load the data using ' ' (space as delimiter) and then format the comma separated values using TOKENIZE function and FLATTEN the data to achieve the objective.

Answer (score 1):

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'a.csv' AS USING PigStorage(' ') (key:chararray, value:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE key, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(value, ','));
DUMP B;
```

**Input : a.csv :**

```
1234 #one,#two,#three
5679 #one,#two
1234 #one
```

**Output : DUMP B:**

```
(1234,#one)
(1234,#two)
(1234,#three)
(5679,#one)
(5679,#two)
(1234,#one)
```