# Hadoop Pig. Changing structure

Tags: hadoop, structure, apache-pig

Can you help me to change the structure of my file?

For example:

1. I have a string with 2 delimiters:

   ```
   1;2,3,4;2
   ```
2. I want to change it to raws with 1 delimiter:

   ```
   1;2;2
   1;3;2
   1;4;2
   ```

Comment: We can load the data using ';' (semicolon delimiter) and then format the comma separated values using TOKENIZE function and FLATTEN the data to achieve the objective. Had answered similar kind of question few days back, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061504/loading-unstructered-data-with-different-delimiters-in-pig-using-piglatin-only/31062977#31062977

Answer (score 1):

**Pig Script :**

```
 A = LOAD 'a.csv' USING PigStorage(';') AS (value1:chararray,value2:chararray,value3:chararray);
 B = FOREACH A GENERATE value1, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(value2, ',')), value3;
 DUMP B;
```

**Input :**

```
1;2,3,4;2
```

**Output :**

```
(1,2,2)
(1,3,2)
(1,4,2)
```

We can store B using ; as delimiter.

```
 STORE B INTO 'requiredOutputLocation' USING PigStorage(';');
```